# How enable & disable some javascript function using radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="radio_btn">
  <ul class="tg-list">
    <li class="tg-list-item">
        <input class="tgl tgl-skewed" id="cb3" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="tgl-btn" data-tg-off="OFF" data-tg-on="ON" for="cb3"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to disable & enable the javascript code (below) using the above radio button.

**Javascript**

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('box2');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Assign your `window.setInterval` to a variable, and then when the radio button is checked, call `clearInterval()` on that variable. I.e. `var myInterval = window.setInterval(...);` and `clearInterval(myInterval)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no radio button. But to toggle the interval, save an ID you can clear

```js
var tId;
$(function() {
  $("#cb3").on("click", function() {
    if (this.checked) tId = setInterval(
      function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('box2');
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
      }, 1000);
    else clearInterval(tId);
  });
});
```